# ASP.NET Opening Excel Sheet Error: MS Access DB Engine cannot open or write to the file..."

Tags: asp.net, ms-access, permissions

I'm getting an error message when trying to open an excel sheet from my ASP.NET website:

> The Microsoft Access database engine cannot open or write to the file ''. It is already opened exclusively by another user, or you need permission to view and write its data.

I'm wondering if this has to do with me playing around with the "Owner" of my documents folder today.

How can I resolve this?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to grant the NETWORK SERVICE account modify permission on my folder.